# How to get text value in a div vs. an alert modal - jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, html, modal-dialog

Does anyone have an easy way to have text in a div show what's changed in the following statement vs. an alert modal? I can't seem to get my head around it. Thanks...

```
    $(function(){

            var abc = $('select#percent').selectToUISlider();
                labels: 0
            $('select#valueA, select#valueB').selectToUISlider({
labels: 0,
sliderOptions: {
change:function(e, ui) {
alert('changed'+$('select#valueA option').eq(ui.values[0]).text());
alert('changed'+$('select#valueB option').eq(ui.values[1]).text());
}
}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your alerts to:

```
$('div1 selector').html('changed'+$('select#valueA option').eq(ui.values[0]).text());
$('div2 selector').html('changed'+$('select#valueB option').eq(ui.values[1]).text());
```

Comment: rockin' thanks very much! - note to newbs like me - make sure to use $('#dviname') if you want it to appear in a div with that ID.

Answer (score 0):

$("div.response").html( ui.value );